# ASP.NET Membership Email Verification

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

Trying to create an email verification in C# based on [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153319/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/062508-1.aspx).

I've created a jangosmtp account to send the email. However it doesn't seem to be working.

Web.config:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network
             host="relay.example.com" port="25" userName="********" password="********" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Registration.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" DisableCreatedUser="True">
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server" />
            <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server" />
        </WizardSteps>
        <MailDefinition BodyFileName="NewAccountTemplate.htm" From="example@example.com" IsBodyHtml="True"  Subject="Steps to activate your new account..." Priority="High" />
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
</asp:Content>
```

Registration.aspx.cs:

```
namespace WebSite
{
    public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void CreateUserWizard1_SendingMail(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            //Send an email to the address on file
            MembershipUser userInfo = Membership.GetUser(CreateUserWizard1.UserName);

            //Construct the verification URL
            string verifyUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Page.ResolveUrl("~/Verify.aspx?ID=" + userInfo.ProviderUserKey.ToString());

            //Replace <%VerifyUrl%> placeholder with verifyUrl value
            e.Message.Body = e.Message.Body.Replace("<%VerifyUrl%>", verifyUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

NewAccountTemplate.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Steps to activate your account...</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Verdana;">

    <h2>
        Welcome to My Website!</h2>
    <p>
        Hello, <%UserName%>. You are receiving this email because you recently created a new account at my 
        site. Before you can login, however, you need to first visit the following link:</p>
    <p>
        <a href="<%VerifyUrl%>"><%VerifyUrl%></a></p>
    <p>
        After visiting the above link you can log into the site!</p>
    <p>
        If you have any problems verifying your account, please reply to this email to 
        get assistance.</p>
    <p>
        Thanks!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Verify.aspx.cs:

```
namespace WebSite
{
    public partial class Verify : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Make sure that a valid query string value was passed through
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ID"]) || !Regex.IsMatch(Request.QueryString["ID"], "[0-9a-f]{8}\\-([0-9a-f]{4}\\-){3}[0-9a-f]{12}"))
            {
                InformationLabel.Text = "An invalid ID value was passed in through the querystring.";
            } else {
                //ID exists and is kosher, see if this user is already approved
                //Get the ID sent in the querystring
                Guid userId = new Guid(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

                //Get information about the user
                MembershipUser userInfo = Membership.GetUser(userId);
                if (userInfo == null) {
                    //Could not find user!
                    InformationLabel.Text = "The user account could not be found in the membership database.";
                } else {
                    //User is valid, approve them
                    userInfo.IsApproved = true;
                    Membership.UpdateUser(userInfo);

                    //Display a message
                    InformationLabel.Text = "Your account has been verified and you can now log into the site.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Two things concerning me which is what im assuming is not causing it to work.

1. How does it know to even send NewAccountTemplate.htm message? UPDATE ahh i  see where that happens in the createuserwizard1 now. Still getting this error message.
2. On NewAccountTemplate.htm i get a warning message:

> Warning '<% VerifyUrl %>' was not found.

What's going wrong? Am i overlooking something.

UPDATE 2:

If i add onsendingmail="CreateUserWizard1_SendingMail" It generate a link, however the link does not work because the user never gets added into the database i checked this. So when i click the link on the email it says bad request obv due to the fact there is no user with this ID. If i remove that line of code the user gets created but no link gets generated :/

Comment: Assuming you just accidentally posted your account credentials... change them! o_O

Comment: It's just a free tester one i created for this purpose. Changed anyway.

Comment: Any ideas as to why it's not working?

Comment: Your code makes reference to an ASP.NET Wizard Control, but I can't see you using it.

Comment: Check post, i edited it to show my registration.aspx code.

Comment: UPDATE: ok ive got it to send the email now, but because theres an error on verifyurl there is no link to click on the email :/

Comment: I may have fixed my problem! There is some mixup going on, one time i didint recieve the email. So now when i clcik verification link its saying The user account could not be found in the membership database. because the verification id on the link is Verification.aspx?ID=1454e7b9-99d3-4089-9922-f9339c0313a3  but the userid on the database is 8251E8AE-600C-42E5-8C60-1949A667B2B8 which is different :/

Comment: Tried again, Jangomail smtp, sometimes doesen't send the email to my email account but i can see it on the jango account logs. that it has recieved the request, due to this i'm getting some problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work.

1. onsendingmail="CreateUserWizard1_SendingMail" This should be in create user wizard.

   ```
   <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server" onsendingmail="CreateUserWizard1_SendingMail">
   <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" DisableCreatedUser="True">
       <WizardSteps>
           <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server" />
           <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server" />
       </WizardSteps>
       <MailDefinition BodyFileName="NewAccountTemplate.htm" From="example@example.com" IsBodyHtml="True"  Subject="Steps to activate your new account..." Priority="High" />
   </asp:CreateUserWizard>
   ```
2. use just <%VerificationUrl%> in NewAccountTemplate.htm
3. Change registration.aspx.cs to

   ```
   // Get the UserId of the just-added user
   MembershipUser newUser = Membership.GetUser(CreateUserWizard1.UserName);
   Guid newUserId = (Guid)newUser.ProviderUserKey;

   // Determine the full verification URL (i.e., http://yoursite.com/Verification.aspx?ID=...)
   string urlBase = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath;
   string verifyUrl = "Verify.aspx?ID=" + newUserId.ToString();
   string fullUrl = urlBase + verifyUrl;

   // Replace <%VerificationUrl%> with the appropriate URL and querystring
   e.Message.Body = e.Message.Body.Replace("<%VerificationUrl%>", fullUrl);
   ```