# Encrypt user's record index

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, cryptography

My ASP.NET MVC web application creates some data on behalf of a user and stores it in a SQL database in a record with a numeric primary key.  I access the data via the primary key.

I want my authenticated users to be able to navigate to a URL that contains the (numeric) primary key, but I don't want to expose the actual key value.  So, it seems to me that I would want to encrypt the numeric key (using a symmetrical encryption algorithm) with a password consisting of a string baked into my code plus the logged-in user's UserID.  The resultant URL would look something like: `https://foo.com/123abc`, where "123abc" is the encrypted key value (converted from bytes to characters).  In theory (to my beginner brain) this encrypted value, even if acquired by a malicious party, would not be useful unless that party could log in to my website using the user's credentials.

**Question 1:** Is this the correct way to do this sort of thing, and
**Question 2:** Can someone who knows this stuff point me at a simple symmetrical encryption API that I can use for this purpose.

Comment: Why don't you want the user seeing the PK?

Comment: My answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15068881/637783

Comment: @msarchet: I don't want someone to be able to come to the website and look at someone else's data, which would be possible if they just provide an unencrypted key.

Comment: @Bob.at.SBS why not just authorize the action?

Comment: @Bob ASP.NET uses sessionID to distinguish users: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479041.aspx

Comment: @Bob.at.SBS there's nothing wrong with exposing the ID on the Url. If you're worried about users not seeing each other's data then: 1) Make sure the controller action requires authentication, and 2) Do a check when you query for the object to see if the current  User.Identity.Name is the same as the username stored on the row you just retrieved from the database, if it's not then just redirect the user to an error page.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use the PK, you can add a column to your SQL table and setting its type to uniqueidentifier and it's value to NEWID() and then display that to the user, this solution would have the least amount of overhead, while still providing a seemingly random series that you can tie back to that user later.

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD foobar uniqueIdentifier default newid();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx

Comment: The identifier is visible to anyone snooping the wire.  Simply making the identifier non-numeric doesn't prevent someone from sniffing the identifier and hitting the website with that identifier in the URL.  I need to ensure that the identifier is only useful to the user whose data is associated with it.

Comment: Your statement is a total falsehood for how ASP.NET, ADO.NET, & SQL interact. I'd recommend doing some research on security if you're concerned, why would the PK or my theoretical column solution be in the URL bar??

Comment: Because that was the scenario I presented in the OP.  I want a user to be able to retrieve his data by specifying the data's unique ID in the URL.  I want to be able to email the URL to a user, and be assured that only that user can use the URL to access his data.

Comment: Never mind, I'm just being dense today. It didn't occur to me to just verify that the authenticated user has the right to access the specified ID (whether or not its numeric).  But if nothing else, I got a cool pair of encryption routines to add to my library.

Comment: But if the users is authenticated, why the extra check?  Also, what authentication technique are you trying to use?

Comment: My website allows users to create reports.  One user, many reports. When the website has a report available, it sends an email to the user with a link to the report.  Assuming that the user is persistently logged in, I want the user to be able to just navigate to the URL and get the report.  If the user isn't logged in then the authentication magic takes 'em to the login page then back to the "fetch a report" page.  So the URL contains the report ID (either the PK or a uniqueidentifier).  But I can't allow someone other than that user to access the report, thus the extra check.

Comment: Put another way, it's not sufficient that the user be authenticated. The authenticated user must also be allowed to access the data specified by the URL parameter (whether it's a pk or a uniqueidentifier).  Without that check then any user with valid credentials could access any user's data simply by knowing the URL parameter.

Comment: what reporting technology are you using? Something like SSRS has built in permissions.  I think what you're looking for is OTP > one time pass keys.  See this to get you started: http://geekswithblogs.net/TheInspiredGecko/archive/2009/02/23/pre-authentication-and-one-time-passkeys-otps-using-asp.net-again.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333613/asp-net-membership-email-verification and

Answer (score 1):

Symmetrical encryption of an integer would be so ridiculously easy to crack you might as well not even bother. Now, you could salt it or obfuscate it a bit by Base64 encoding it or something like that, but still, this is pretty pointless. A database primary key is not sensitive data. It's meaningless without access to the database, and if they have access to the database, looking up a particular user by their id is the absolutely least of your problems. Even symmetrical encryption is going to add significant overhead to your application for something that's simply not necessary.

If you really don't want the PK exposed, then use something else like the username in the URL and look up the user by that.

Comment: Point well taken: basing the ID part of the URL on an encrypted integer is pretty weak.  So I need to use a more complex unique identifier to access my data (as suggested by RandomUs1r), but I still need to modify it such that it is only useable by the intended, authenticated user.  I think that means I need to encrypt it using something that only works when that user is logged in, such as the UserID.

Comment: I think you missed my point. What is the problem you're trying to solve. If a particular URL should only be available to a particular logged in user, that's a job for the controller and/or your standard authorization scheme (`Authorize` attribute, for example) -- not the URL itself. If you don't want information about the user exposed in the URL, *don't put it in the URL*. If you handle authorization appropriate - in the controller - you can have a standard URL (i.e. /profile) that automatically loads the correct user from the authenticated session.

Comment: Never mind... I'm a bit slow.  Not enough caffeine.  So, what you're saying is: rather than trying to fiddle with the URL to encode the user ID in the URL (which is effectively what I'm doing when I use the UserID as salt in a cypher), just ensure that the authenticated user owns the ID specified by the URL.  Simple.  Duh...

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, sure.

Store the salt in your session, generate one randomly every time or use the session ID as salt.

Below are two methods that could encrypt/decrypt your string value with salt. You can use the salt in place of initial vector.

```
public static string Encrypt(string PlainText, string Password, string Salt,
 string HashAlgorithm = "SHA1", int PasswordIterations = 16, string InitialVector = "Initial Vector", int KeySize = 256)
{  
    byte[] InitialVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitialVector);
    byte[] SaltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Salt);
    byte[] PlainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PlainText);
    PasswordDeriveBytes DerivedPassword = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, SaltValueBytes, HashAlgorithm, PasswordIterations);
    byte[] KeyBytes = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(KeySize / 8);
    RijndaelManaged SymmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
    SymmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

    ICryptoTransform Encryptor = SymmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(KeyBytes, InitialVectorBytes);

    MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(MemStream, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cryptoStream.Write(PlainTextBytes, 0, PlainTextBytes.Length);
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    byte[] CipherTextBytes = MemStream.ToArray();

    MemStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();
    Encryptor.Dispose();
    Encryptor = null;

    return Convert.ToBase64String(CipherTextBytes);
}


public static string Decrypt(string CipherText, string Password, string Salt,
    string HashAlgorithm = "SHA1", int PasswordIterations = 16, string InitialVector = "Initial Vector", int KeySize = 256)
{ 
    byte[] InitialVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitialVector);
    byte[] SaltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Salt);
    byte[] CipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(CipherText);
    PasswordDeriveBytes DerivedPassword = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, SaltValueBytes, HashAlgorithm, PasswordIterations);
    byte[] KeyBytes = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(KeySize / 8);
    RijndaelManaged SymmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
    SymmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

    ICryptoTransform Decryptor = SymmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(KeyBytes, InitialVectorBytes);
    MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream(CipherTextBytes);
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(MemStream, Decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    byte[] PlainTextBytes = new byte[CipherTextBytes.Length];

    int ByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(PlainTextBytes, 0, PlainTextBytes.Length);

    MemStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();
    Decryptor.Dispose();
    Decryptor = null;

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(PlainTextBytes, 0, ByteCount);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm fuzzy on the difference between the salt and the IV (especially since you said I can "use the salt in place of the IV"). In my application, I think I would use my secret string as the password, the authenticated user name as the salt, and just leave InitialVector with its default value of "Initial Vector".  Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for the code sample!!! (I know, don't waste bytes thanking people...) A couple of comments on the above code: (1) The default value of "Initial Vector" doesn't work - it has to be 16 characters long.  And (2) the OP said I want to use the result in a URL. A Base64String doesn't work as a token in a URL.  After a bit of digging, I found System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode when yields a much happier string.

Comment: You are correct about both things and I'm sure these are both minor problems. I "sanitized" the code since it comes from production, so the initial vector was set without testing. The UrlEncode you already figured out. And instead of wasting bytes thanking you can always +1 (: